# Implementing operator<< with a class::factory();

Tags: c++, templates, operator-overloading

I have a generic (pure virtual interface) class IFACE, and some class that handles all subclasses of IFACE as follows:

```
class IFACE{
};

class A{
public:  
   A& operator<<(IFACE& other);      
};
```

Everything works fine with the following:

```
class B:IFACE{
};
```

But not with factory methods as follows:

```
class C:IFACE{
  static C factory(){
    C c;
    return c;
  }
}
```

With executable:

```
int main(){
  A a;
  B b;
  C c;
  C cc = C::factory();
  a<<b;               //Ok ...
  a<<c;               //Also ok...
  a<<cc;              //Again ok ...
  a<<C::factory();    //error below
  return 0;
}
```

`error: no match for ‘operator<<’ in ‘A << C::factory()()’`

Also fails( same error):

```
 a<<(C::factory());
```

Now, the following works: `a<<&(C::factory());` but gives a warning about taking the address of temporary. I assume this is unsafe because I can't control when the anon result of C::factory() will go out of scope. **Is this unsafe?**

So my next thought is:

```
class A{
  A& operator<<(IFACE* ifp);
  template<typename T>
  A& operator<<(T t){
    IFACE* ifp = static_cast<IFACE*>(&t);
    return (*this)<<ifp;
  }
}
```

Which compiles fine, but linking `main` from above gives the error:

`undefined reference to 'A& A::operator<< <C>(C)'`

**How can this be undefined?**

EDIT:

It has been suggested that I implement:

`A& A::operator<<(const IFACE& other)`

But this also won't compile...
 I get the following error:

`error: passing ‘const IFACE’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘virtual int <some method in IFACE>’ discards qualifiers`

UPDATE:
This problem is still unresolved.

Comment: [Herb Sutter's - A candidate for the most important const](http://herbsutter.com/2008/01/01/gotw-88-a-candidate-for-the-most-important-const/).

Comment: @Josh That function you are using inside `operator<<` must be declared constant; like this: `return_type iTYPE::func() const`.

Answer (score 2):

Eser is right about the cause of the problem, but not the solution. In order to fix this, all you have to do is make the reference constant: `operator<<(const iFACE&)`. Now your operator can also work with temporaries.

*Off-topic:* Instead of doing `C c; return c;` you can just as easily do `return C()`, with the same result, but with one line fewer and possibly easier for the compiler to optimize. :)

Comment: Ah! You made me wanna down vote my own answer. Anyway, I'm deleting it to prevent any confusion.

Comment: re: _off-topic_: there was a lot of removed initialization.  Edit (posted early). How can op<<(const iFACE&) work if iFACE is pure virtual?. I get the following error: ` error: passing ‘const IFACE’ as ‘this’ argument of ‘virtual int <some method in IFACE>’ discards qualifiers